# GCP App Engine Custom Domain -- A Records requested for root domain

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

I have an App Engine service called `my-api`, and I wish to use a custom domain to point to this service. It looks straightforward enough to use a `dispatch.yaml` file to perform the redirect to the service, but when I go to "Add a Custom Domain" in my App Engine settings, the last step asks me to add A records pointing to my root domain.

The problem is that I want to create a custom domain of the form

```
my-api.my-org-domain.com
```

But I don't want to divert traffic to

```
my-org-domain.com
```

which is a WordPress site. However, even when I remove the naked domain from the second step, the last step still requires me to change the IP address of `my-org-domain.com`.

Is it possible to add a custom domain without changing the routing to my naked domain?

**UPDATE**

This has been asked before, and there is advice to only add the CNAME record at the end. However, the CNAME record points only to `ghs.googlehosted.com`, and not to my App Engine service. When I only add the CNAME record, then a GET request to the subdomain gives

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot GET /</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your issue? Are you trying to use `subdomain.example.com` instead of `www.example.com` ?

Comment: It's an API domain. I'm not interested in www. I want to route the API to https://my-api.my-org-domain.com. But I do NOT want to change the routing for https://my-org-domain.com.

Comment: This is basically a duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63187859/mapping-gcp-app-engine-to-a-subdomain-not-naked-domain?rq=2. But the solution suggested there (ignore the A and AAAA records) does not work. Calls to the subdomain give the message "Cannot GET /"

Comment: @RobLyndon, it looks like the error is caused by something else.  If you just have one service, then you don't need `dispatch.yaml` so try without that.

Comment: @newname I have more than one service. My API service is segregated from the default service, because the API is a separate offering to the main app.

Comment: Have you checked with this [Stackoverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43865327/18265702) and also share the complete error message.

Comment: @SandeepVokkareni Thanks for that link, but it hasn't helped much. According to the link I posted, the A records and the AAAA records provided by the wizard are not necessary, but the only other record provided is a CNAME, pointing to ghs.googlehosted.com. I don't see how the automatic redirect to ghs.googlehosted.com can be routed to my App Engine service.

Comment: @SandeepVokkareni It feels like something is fundamentally wrong with the wizard, if I only want to map a subdomain, and the last step tells me to map A and AAAA records that point to my naked domain.

Comment: I'm using Route 53, which has some non-standard ways of defining CNAMEs. I haven't been able to get any kind of mapping working.

Comment: Does this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58696992/17477508) work for you? You may check [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/ResourceRecordTypes.html#CNAMEFormat:~:text=com%22%3C/Value%3E%0A%3C/ResourceRecord%3E-,CNAME%20record%20type,-A%20CNAME%20record) as well.

Comment: Thanks @BadalaPrashanth -- that seems to have fixed the issue. My API is now using the correct domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering as a Community Wiki, so that it may help others too. @Rob Lyndon feel free to add if anything is not covered.

As @Badala Prashanth, shared a [Stackoverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58696992/18265702) which suggested

> To map [test.example.com](http://test.example.com) to the existing project in GCP. Note that you do need to verify ownership of the subdomain. Then delete the existing mapping to that project.
> I did not update the domain custom resource records yet. I switched to the new project in GCP and mapped [example.com](http://example.com) to it. At the step (5) where it said update your domain records, I realized that the A and AAAA records for the 2 projects were exactly the same.
> This was confusing to me. What I realized is that GCP is doing some mapping to the correct project internally, it is not all a DNS thing.
> To update the DNS records I just left the existing DNS records that I already had and added A and AAAA records for [test.example.com](http://test.example.com) with the same values as the existing records. Of course it took a wile for all of the DNS and GCP mapping to flow through.